# Inno Setup appcmd output to file

Tags: iis, inno-setup, appcmd

I've been trying for hours to execute the following Inno Script code.

```
Exec('C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe', 'list site > "c:\test\temp.txt"', '', SW_SHOW, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode)
```

It executes the appcmd program whose output is saved in a file.
The above code doesn't stream the output into a file when run from Inno Script. When I run the code from command line, it works fine. I can also execute the other commands like `ipconfig` and redirect the output to the file.

I've also tried the following code but to no avail.

```
 Exec('cmd.exe', '"/c "C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe" list site > "c:\test\temp.txt"', '', SW_SHOW, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode)
```

I can run other commands like `add site` or `add apppool`. I can see that the cmd window opens but since opening and closing is almost instantaneous, I can't check the output on the window.

The return value of `Exec` is `True`.

I'm not exactly sure what is going wrong as I am not getting any error while executing the code.

Comment: Basically, if you made it working with `ipconfig.exe`, you must have executed it via `cmd.exe`. So execute the `appcmd.exe` the same way as `ipconfig.exe`.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl That's where i looked before I posted this. Exactly, it should have worked. But I'm stumped why this isn't working for appcmd.exe while it's working for cmd.exe

Comment: When I wrap up the code `C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe list sites > c:\civica\test.txt` in a bat file and call that batch file, it seems to work. But isn't that the same thing as executing appcmd from Inno script. Any idea why? @MartinPrikryl

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Also, if i execute other commands like `add site` then it executes the command successfully. I think it's the output redirection that isn't working.

Comment: But in your question you are **not** executing the `appcmd.exe` via `cmd.exe`. If you have tried that, show us the code for that. The code in your question is wrong.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl I meant manually opening command prompt, navigating to the inetsrv folder and typing in the required command like `appcmd list sites > c:\temp\test.txt`.

Comment: You have quotes wrong. This is correct:
 `Exec('cmd.exe', '/c ""C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe" list site > "c:\test\temp.txt""', ...` And of course, use constants (`{cmd}`, `{sys}`, `{tmp}`), where appropriate.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. Surprisingly enough, when I run the appcmd.exe instead of cmd, the output doesn't redirect to a file. I guess I will just use cmd. @MartinPrikryl

Comment: It's not surprising. The output redirection (the `>` symbol) is a feature of the `cmd.exe`. So you have to use it, if you need to redirect the output using `>`. When you are on Windows command-line, you are running the command within `cmd.exe` already (The Windows command-line window in the `cmd.exe`).

Comment: How do I accept the duplicate?

Comment: You should see "That solved my problem" button. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250981/new-ui-encourages-askers-to-confirm-or-dispute-duplicate-votes

Comment: I don't have any such button to accept the duplicate.